# Dropdown menu using css

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have ceated a dropdown menu using the following css

```
.menu li ul {display: none;}
.menu li:hover > ul {display: block;}
```

But the problem is whenever the menu dropsdown the content below shifts down. How can I prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent that by positioning the sub menu absolute.

```
.menu li ul {display: none; position: absolute; }
```

You also have to set

```
.menu { position: relative; }
```

as said in the comment by Tae. If you do not, the sub menu will probably set to the top left corner of the page.

Comment: Don't forget to make the menu `position:relative;`, or the submenu will be positioned relative to the browser window.